Solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^TS\underline{a}_1-\lambda (\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1-1)\right]$

Portion from Lecture Notes
Via the mechanics of Principal Component Analysis, we need to compute $\frac{\partial Q} {\partial\underline{a}_1}:$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^TS\underline{a}_1-\lambda (\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1-1)\right]=S\underline{a}_1-\lambda \underline{a}_1\tag{1}$$
Setting this equal to zero gives:
\begin{align*}
S\underline{a}_1-\lambda\underline{a}_1&=0\\
\Rightarrow S\underline{a}_1&=\lambda\underline{a}_1
\end{align*}
i.e. $\underline{a}_1$ is an eigenvector of $S$.

My Attempt
I had a go at solving $(1)$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^TS\underline{a}_1-\lambda (\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1-1)\right]\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^TS\underline{a}_1\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\lambda(\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1-1)\right]\\
&=S\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1\right]-\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[(\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1-1)\right]\\
&=S\left(\underline{a}_1\times 1\right)-\lambda\left((\underline{a}_1\times 1-1)\right)\\
&=S\underline{a}_1-\lambda \underline{a}_1\\
\end{align*}
Is this correct? I used this matrix derivatives cribsheet where $\textbf{X}^T\textbf{b}\rightarrow\textbf{b}$ for $\underline{a}_1^T\rightarrow\underline{a}_1$, but was unsure.

You're using the wrong identity from the cheatsheet you linked. You can't use
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}$$ if $\mathbf{b}$ is dependent on $\mathbf{x}$.
The identity from the cheatsheet you actually need is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Bx}=2\mathbf{Bx}$$
which you apply after Line 2 in your attempt. (Currently the equality between Lines 2 and 3 are wrong)
There's another error you made, which can be fixed by noting $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}1=\mathbf{0}$$

Many thanks! Would I be getting a little closer here?$$\begin{align*}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\underline{a}_1^TS\underline{a}_1\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[\lambda(\underline{a}_1^T\underline{a}_1)\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_1}}\left[1\right]\
&=2S\underline{a}_1-2\lambda\underline{a}_1\
&=2(S\underline{a}_1-\lambda\underline{a}_1)\
\end{align*}$$

Change the last "-" to a "+" in the last term of Line 1 and you're good :)

Thanks! If I added another term at the end (for practice), would this work?$$\begin{align*}&\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_2}}\left[\underline{a}_2^TS\underline{a}_2\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_2}}\left[\lambda(\underline{a}_2^T\underline{a}_2)\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial{\underline{a}_2}}\left[1\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial\underline{a}_2}\left[\phi\underline{a}^T_2\underline{a}_1\right]\
&=2S\underline{a}_2-2\lambda\underline{a}_2+0-2\phi\underline{a}_1\
&=2\left(S\underline{a}_2-\lambda\underline{a}_2-\phi\underline{a}_1\right)
\end{align*}$$
